# css cursor using data-uri

Tags: css, data-uri, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to use custom png cursor using data uri but the cursor doesn't change.
I've tested on FF 17 which support png as custom cursor.
The same data uri work as a background image.

Am I using wrong syntax or maybe data-uri can't be used as a cursor image?

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/u8t3j/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>cursor test</title>
<style>
        #cursor {
          width: 300px;
          height: 300px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          cursor: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
        }

        #background {
          width: 300px;
          height: 300px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          margin-top: 10px;
          background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cursor"></div>
  <div id="background"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The answer works for png in FF and Chrome so I'm adding an example for .cur image that doesn't work in IE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>cursor test</title>
<style>
        #cursor {
          width: 300px;
          height: 300px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          cursor: url(data:application/cur;base64,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), pointer;
        }

        #background {
          width: 300px;
          height: 300px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          margin-top: 10px;
          background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cursor"></div>
  <div id="background"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion, when using especially when using Base64 within CSS, it might be a good idea to compress images before converting. For example, (for one-off's) I'll optimize with [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com) then convert with [b64.io](https://b64.io) (which compresses further, if possible).  The example cursor data-uri above was a **5744b** file, and it compressed to only **781b** of Base64, which is less than **⅐ᵗʰ the size**.  (Also sometimes handy is [base64.guru](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image) for decoding Base64 back to an image if necessary.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add `, auto` after your data url like such:

```
cursor: url(data:image/png;base64,...), auto;
```

Not sure why this fixes the problem.

Comment: You should set the fall back to `auto` not default. Default falls back onto browser default, where auto determines which cursor should be shown based on context ([source](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/cursor))

Comment: I've looked at the spec, and it doesn't suggest that the cursor property must have backups if a url is specified. Seems like a Firefox bug. I'll post details if I find or report bug on it.

Comment: What about .cur image for IE9? The following works In FF and Chrome but not in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/zjzT8/

Comment: I haven't tested it, but IE9 should progress through the list until it finds a resource it can use. The last specified cursor should always be a system one.

Comment: @pablo from my own testing, cur data-urls are not supported. However you can use a div, with the cursor set as the background-image, and then update the div's location using JavaScript. Out of Chrome, FireFox and IE 9, IE is the only one that doesn't lag horribly.

Answer (score 2):

Cursor data-uri's are not supported in IE. IE also doesn't support PNGs as cursors. So the best fallback I could get for this case was the following: (tested on IE, Edge, Chrome, FF, Safari

```
style.cssText += ";cursor:url('cursors/" + file + ".cur'), auto;"; // For IE
style.cssText += ";cursor:url('cursors/" + file + ".cur') 16 16, auto;"; // For other browsers - this will do nothing in IE
```