# SVG for cursor says invalid property value

Tags: css, svg

I would like to change the cursor to an SVG when the cursor is within `#square`. I have attempted below by minifying the SVG and setting the `cursor` value in CSS, however, I'm getting the error:

> Invalid Property Value

What am I doing wrong here? Any help to greatly appreciated.

```css
#square {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg id='Layer_1' data-name='Layer 1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='16' width='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Ccircle cx='8' cy='8' r='8'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css cursor using data-uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932291/css-cursor-using-data-uri)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a fallback

```
cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,..."), auto;
```

```css
#square {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg id='Layer_1' data-name='Layer 1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='16' width='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Ccircle cx='8' cy='8' r='8'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"), auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```

read this:[MDN Using URL values for the cursor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property)

Comment: For next time, you can improve your answer by clicking "Copy snippet to answer" from the question's snippet, then edit that snippet with your fix.

Answer (score 0):

You will also get this error if you try to assign:

```
height: 250
```

instead of

```
height: 250px
```

Like the error says, you should scrutinize the *value* and see if it's the kind of thing that that property expects.